# Why are some producers in a song's title?

Tags: song-title

I have noticed that sometimes the name of a song's producer is in the title although usually just the singers/vocalists are in the title. Most of the producers who do make it on the title of a song are pretty mainstream and well-known. Sometimes, producers have their own album or collab album and they are in the title of every song in the album. Who/what decides whether the producer is in a song's title and why?

Comment: There is no strict rules on titles and artists names. Reasons vary and when a group of artists are working together, which one will appear in which order is just a matter of negotiations and agreements.

Comment: Some producers have a significant part in the sound that gets created so they deserve the credit.